# Where is the default text object font (Bfont)?

Tags: text-object, path

I've found `bmonofont-i18n.ttf.gz` and `droidsans.ttf.gz` in the `datafiles/fonts` directory, but neither seems to be the default font that's actually used for Text objects.

Here's how the default font looks:
[image: default.png]

Here's bmonofont-i18n.ttf:
[image: bmono.png]

droidsans.ttf:
[image: droidsans.ttf]

Clearly, the fonts I've found are not the same as the actual default.

I want to find the actual default.

Comment: It's probably packed in.

Comment: @someonewithpc I just need the original ttf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The font is `bfont.pfb`

This is a built-in font which means it  is compiled into blender. The font file is available from the blender source tree in `release/datafiles`

You can access and download the file, e.g., from the GIT repository at blender.org:

http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/tree/HEAD:/release/datafiles

In the directory listing, search for the file `bfont.pfb` and click in the rightmost column on "raw" to download and save the file.

**Or try this direct link:**

http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/release/datafiles/bfont.pfb

Comment: I made the mistake of assuming that bfont.pfb contained the same glyphs as bfont.ttf

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem. Infact, the Blender-inbuilt bfont.ttf is far not the same as the built-in pfb font.
My solution was to convert the pfb into ttf with fontforge. It worked well.
Here ist the correct TrueType Font: http://www.filedropper.com/bfont

Comment: Hi SE, well noted. I have edited my previous answer and and added a solution, pls check the edited answer, thank you!

Comment: Great Martin! Gill Sans should work as well...